# Opening an application via C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to write a simple C PROGAM which EXECUTE a Python SCRIPT (and let it running...) and closes itself.

I tried the following commands but in both cases the C PROGRAM is still alive...

```
popen("sudo python /home/pi/main.py", "r");
system("sudo python /home/pi/main.py");
```

Thanks!

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Edited !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I tried this command based on your comments but no success:

```
char *argv[] = {"/home/pi/main.py"};
execv("sudo python", argv);
```

Anyone could help? Thanks!

!!!!!!!!!!! Edit 2 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

This is how I compile it:

```
gcc -Wall restart.c -o safekill
```

This is the C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

my_popen(char cmd[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to run command\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Read the output a line at a time - output it
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", path);
    }

    pclose(fp);

}

int main()
{
    my_popen("sudo killall python");
    sleep(1);
    my_popen("sudo killall raspivid");
    sleep(1);

    if(fork())
        printf("Am I here?");
        return 0;

    char *file = "restart";
    char *argv[] = {file, "-c", "sudo python main.py", NULL};
    execvp(file, argv);
}
```

Result: It prints am I here and doesn't start the python.
It is so frustrating.... :-(

Comment: [exec](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)?

Comment: You don't *open an application*, you *execute a program*. See [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch while you are technically correct, the command name `popen` seems to disagree with you.

Comment: [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) -a library function, not a command- is opening a pipe stream; the  `p` is for "pipe" (see [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)...) not "program".

Comment: BTW, you might *carefully* read about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) to avoid the `sudo`.

Comment: I think you should fork another thread of execution to run the program ( a demon one/detach it) then the current thread will end when reaching the return statement or you can explicitly use exit(0) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the filename of the program itself to the argument list (`argv[0]`) and terminate the argument list with a NULL pointer.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    if(fork())
        return 0;
    char *file = "python";
    char *argv[] = {file, "-c", "import time; time.sleep(5); print 'Hello'", NULL};
    execvp(file, argv);    
}
```

Expected behavior: Immediate (parent) program termination and a short `Hello` printed 5 seconds later by the child.

Maybe you need to workaround the `sudo` somehow, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately it didn't work. I edited the question with the steps and the result. Thanks!

Comment: @user1688175 You might want to check the return value of the exec command. Maybe `strerror(errno);` will help in this case. But I think finding the exact command that will restart your python script is beyond the scope of this question, after all. You might want to post another question once you got that one step working.